# after config `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, ssh works well but scp does not work

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I change this file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in remote server, shown below, and want to run a script when ssh to it.
`#Flyakite
command="/home/path/to/script" ssh-rsa my-key`

now if I run `ssh $USER@$HOST x1 x2 x3`, it works fine, however, if I run `scp path/to/file $USER@$HOST:path/to/file`, it does not work...

what is the problem? How can I make it work?

Comment: " it does not work..." -- because the file(s) you copied aren't present on the target, but there was no error message?  Or there was an error message that you need help understanding?

Comment: @BrianCain, there is no error message. "are not present on the target?" I am not quite understand about it, could you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that particular key,  add "command=" to the key, means cannot run anything else other than that script, it has limited access to that server.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `scp` works by executing a command on the server. But if you force your target system to execute a different command, `scp` cannot work any longer.

You could put a script on the target host which recognizes an `scp` command and executes it, and if none is recognized, your "default" program is invoked instead.